# Dependent drop down on filter

Tags: django, django-filter

Previously I implemented a dependent drop down on my model form (car manufacture to manufactures models) [based on this blog post](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html). Now I have a section on my site for users to view the cars with a filter for the manufacture to model. The only issue is that if you select a manufacture you have a list of every model not just the ones that are linked to that manufacture. If you could please point me in the right direction on how I would go about creating a dependent drop down on a filter.

filter

```
class carFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
class Meta: 
    model = Post
    fields = 'manufacture', 'model'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide a custom form for the filterset by specifying it in the `Meta` as described in the [documentation](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filterset.html#custom-forms-using-form). After this would be a similar process to the one described in your linked [blog post](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html). So your forms implementation would be something like:

```
from django import forms


class CarFilterForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Assuming model name as "model", if it really is that you might want to change it
        self.fields['model'].queryset = Model.objects.none()
        if 'manufacture' in self.data:
            try:
                manufacture_id = int(self.data.get('manufacture'))
                self.fields['model'].queryset = Model.objects.filter(manufacture_id=manufacture_id)
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                pass
        # No pre-existing instance since this is a form for filtering, so the other condition is not needed


class carFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta: 
        model = Post
        fields = 'manufacture', 'model'
        form = CarFilterForm
```

After this you would write JavaScript and a view similar to as you would have done as described in the blog post.

---

> **Note**: class names should ideally be in `PascalCase` not `camelCase`, hence instead of <s>`carFilter`</s> you should use
> **`CarFilter`**. Please see [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for
> Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Thanks so much! Not very good with JS / jQuery but going to give it a shot!